# Create Fitnesse pages without using Camel-Case

Tags: testing, fitnesse

I am currently migrating a huge amount of scripts to Fitnesse. I implemented a converter that takes the existing scripts XML and converts them to Fitnesse Files (e.g. content.txt). This is working correctly. However, I am still facing a problem with the names since they are not camel-case formatted (an example of a script name is the following: BANK_Tran_BankStmtLoad_Add). Most of the scripts have such names. It is possible to programatically remove the "_" but this won't work as well since we still have several consecutive capital letters. Is there a way to create new pages in Fitnesse without having to write the names in Camel-case.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is baked into FitNesse.  I tried manually creating the FitNesse folders but no luck.  You can run tests outside FitNesse with Folder Runner: http://fitsharp.github.com/Fit/FolderRunner.html or http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.FitLibraryUserGuide.FolderRunner

Comment: Thanks for your comment. However, I was able to fix the issue by creating a regular expression that transforms the names into Camel case. Now all the scripts are migrated correctly. I will be looking at your solution soon :)